# I don't know how to add a filter function in my program to remove same elements, especially '(', ')' and same words

Tags: python

```
def doc_read_alpha():

    with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            f_contents = file.read()
            lines = line.split()
            lines = sorted(lines)
```

The above is an algorithm used to iterate through my file contents and separate each word into an element of an array 'lines'. I am having trouble adding a filter function which would remove duplicates from my array.

```
    input_file_string = " ".join(lines)

    return lines


def main():
    print(doc_read_alpha())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: tried the .strip() method, didn't work. Would love help on implementing an algorithm which would remove duplicates, brackets and quotation marks. Would settle just for duplicate removal

Comment: Can you paste a dummy values of input.txt?

Comment: The `for line in file:` loop followed by `file.read()` seems strange.

Comment: sure, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: A set will keep only unique elements. Wrap it in list to convert it back to a list. `list(set(lines))`
Other algorithms here https://www.dotnetperls.com/duplicates-python

Comment: @Matthias it was there, because of past projects

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: *"it was there, because of past projects"*: This makes **NO** sense at all! You are reading from `file` **twice**.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have a list of unique words/tokens extracted from a text. You can achieve that through a "set" instead of a list, which behaves almost identically as a list, but does not allow for duplicate entries.

It is as simple as:

```
lines = set(line.split())
```

Comment: This will only work if each line has exactly one word.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid duplicates in your list. A better solution would be to use a set. Each element in the set is unique and does not repeat.

you can convert your list into a set using

```
s = set(lines)
```

However, sets are unordered and while it makes it faster to check if a value belongs in the set. It means you cannot find an element using an index

Answer (score 0):

```
def doc_read_alpha():
    with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
        s = set()
        for line in file.readlines():
            s.update(line.split())
    return s
```

I dont know if this is the best solution but it works. However this method does count "word" and "word." as two different words. To avoid this you have do strip all non letter characters.